# How to reopen a closed form without dispose errors or retaining previous data?

Tags: c#, forms, show, dispose

I have a main form(Form1) and a secondary form(AddProd). On Form1 I have a button that opens AddProd. This is the event code.

```
private void button69_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pIdVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        editAdd = true;
        addProd.Show();
    }
```

"pIdVal" is an int that represents the ID of the selected record to be displayed.
"editAdd" is a bool value that will tell AddProd if the user wishes to edit selected info,  or add new info.

The issue I'm having is that when the user closes AddProd after they either edit, add, or cancel, the form becomes disposed if I used this.Close(). Which doesn't allow AddProd to be opened again unless I restart the whole program. And if I try to reopen it, I receive and error message that says "Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AddProd'." I've also tried to use this.Hide() in place of this.Close(). It keeps me from getting a disposed error. But if I select a new record and then open AddProd again, the data from the previously selected record is still in the text boxes.

To help to better understand my problem fully. Form1 displays a dataGridView of products for the user to see. The user can then select a row of data to edit, or the user can add a new row of data. Once the user selects a row, they then press the Edd/View(button69) button. This opens AddProd with the text boxes filled in with the selected rows data. Once the user edits or views the data and closes AddProd, they chose a different row and press Edd/View button again. Only this time, the data displayed is that of the previously selected row and not the currently selected row. Unless, of course, I use this.Close(). In which case AddProd doesn't reopen, it just errors.

Sorry if I was a bit repetitive. I just want to make sure there is no issue with the question. Any help?

Comment: `button69`, seriously?! Don't you ever give names to your controls?

Comment: to be honest, not really. i know i shouldn't do it that way, but i'm used to it. i use comments and placement to identify my code. i don't like to bother naming every single button and textbox. i have over 280 textboxes in my program and over a 100 buttons. and that's just in the main form.

Comment: Well, that's even more reason to give them names... with only numbers, the only way to know what a control is for is to open the designer, which is a pain. There's no way to guess by just looking at the code.

Comment: i organize and label my code as soon as its created. i can actually find the chunk of code i need and now what its for very quickly. but you are right. what i do goes against everything i've ever learned in class. but sometimes people find a system that works better for them. like the woman that never used filing cabinets for the files in the movie tommy boy.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new instance of AddProd:

```
private void button69_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pIdVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
    editAdd = true;
    AddProd addProd = new AddProd();
    addProd.Show();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the textboxes wouldn't display the data when AddProd was opened. I forgot to mention that above. But I'll give it another try tomorrow, i have to call it quits for today unfortunately.

Comment: Problem fixed. I made AddProd_Load public. And in the button code I added addProd.AddProd_Load(sender, e), to reload the form each time the button is clicked.